# protocol=4 pickle (python 3.7): Keyerror when load dicts with the same key inside

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I'm running python3.7.9-64bit installed by anaconda on Mac.
Just happens to meet three problems.

(Though I write fix_import=False, changing this does not make any difference)
**1st Problem**, if two dicts with the same key got pickled in one file, loading the 2nd dict will **raise KeyError**.

```
import pickle

d1={"a":1}# if two dicts has the same key
d2={"a":0}# does not matter what value is stored.

tmpf=open("deleteThis","wb")
pkl=pickle.Pickler(tmpf,protocol=4,fix_imports=False)
pkl.dump(d1)
pkl.dump(d2)
tmpf.close()

tmpf2=open("deleteThis","rb")
td1=pickle.load(tmpf2)
td2=pickle.load(tmpf2)# KeyError 1
```

**2nd Problem**, though it probably relates to the first one, if the 2nd dict has a dict *D* inside it which share the same key with the 1st dict, then ***D*'s key changes** when loaded.

```
d1={"a":1}
d2={"lll":{"a":2} }# this "a" will always be "lll"

tmpf=open("deleteThis","wb")
pkl=pickle.Pickler(tmpf,protocol=4,fix_imports=True)
pkl.dump(d1)
pkl.dump(d2)
tmpf.close()

tmpf2=open("deleteThis","rb")
td1=pickle.load(tmpf2)
td2=pickle.load(tmpf2)
print(td1,td2)# {'a': 1} {'lll': {'lll': 2}}
```

**3rd Problem**, and the most devastating to me, if there is a dict get pickle.dump and the 2nd dumped dict has a list of dicts sharing the same key, loading the 2nd dict **raise KeyError**.

```
d1={"b":0}
d2={ "l":[{"a":2} , {"a",3}] }

tmpf=open("deleteThis","wb")
pkl=pickle.Pickler(tmpf,protocol=4,fix_imports=True)
pkl.dump(d1)
pkl.dump(d2)
tmpf.close()

tmpf2=open("deleteThis","rb")
td1=pickle.load(tmpf2)
td2=pickle.load(tmpf2)# KeyError
```

These problems only happens with `pickle( protocol=4 )`.
Nothing goes wrong with `protocol=3`
Unknown about python>3.8 or `protocl=5`

Comment: Please don't modify your question with solutions; that's what the answers are for. If the answers are inadequate, you can posted your own, but mingling answers in your question is strongly discouraged (among other things, it makes it impossible to vote on the quality of that "answer"). I've rolled it back to the state it was in before you started editing in solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is to use [`pickle.Unpickler()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler) to load your pickles.

Alternatively, don't use `pickle.Pickler()`. Instead write each pickle with `pickle.dump()` and read back with `pickle.load()` or `pickle.Unpickler()`.

Either one of those should cure your problem.

---

I can confirm that the same problem that you describe exists in Python 3.9.1 for both protocol versions 4 and 5.

BTW: notice that `{"a",3}` in your last example is a set, not a dict as you thought. Nevertheless the same error will occur.

The problem is that `Pickler` uses a memo to cache data that it has pickled. It uses this to economise on the size of the resulting file by avoiding storing the same data more than once. The memo is shared between all pickles written with the `Pickler`.

The `Unpickler` uses the memo to reconstruct the pickled objects that share cached data. However, `pickle.load()` does not use the memo and can therefore fail to find the values that the `Pickler` memoized when it dumped the individual pickles.

---

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
import pickle

d1 = {"b": 0}
d2 = {"l": [{"a": 2}, {"a": 3}]}

with open("deleteThis", "wb") as tmpf:
    pkl = pickle.Pickler(tmpf, protocol=4)
    for obj in d1, d2:
        pkl.dump(obj)

# reload objects with Unpickler - will work.
with open("deleteThis", "rb") as tmpf:
    unpkl = pickle.Unpickler(tmpf)
    print('Using Unpickler')
    while True:
        try:
            print(unpkl.load())
        except EOFError:
            break

# reload objects with pickle.load - might work, but won't here.
with open("deleteThis", "rb") as tmpf:
    print('Using pickle.load()')
    while True:
        try:
            print(pickle.load(tmpf))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

And it's output:

```
Using Unpickler
{'b': 0}
{'l': [{'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]}
Using pickle.load()
{'b': 0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/z.py", line 26, in 
    print(pickle.load(tmpf))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: Memo value not found at index 6
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Can you also verify that pickle.Unpickler(tmpf).load() also will not work in this case for the same reason?

Comment: @dsASDW: No. `pickle.Unpickler()` will work in all cases.